# displaying the circle in kilometers around the curent location in google map

Tags: java, android

kilometers are given in drop down list after selecting the kilometer the circle will display in kilometers in google map, I done this it is displaying, but now I changed something now the circle is not displaying in google map I don't know what I done pls check and correct this code.

this is my code,

```
ArrayAdapter adapter_kilometers = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, kilometers);
adapter_kilometers.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
km.setAdapter(adapter_kilometers);

@Override public void onItemSelected(AdapterView parent, View view, int position, long id) {
 String k = km.getSelectedItem().toString();
 Integer km = Integer.parseInt(k);
 Integer kilometer = km * 1000;
 getRadius(kilometer);
}
void getRadius(int kilometer) {
 if (circle != null) {
  circle.remove();
 }
 Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions().center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude)).radius(kilometer).strokeColor(Color.RED).fillColor(Color.BLUE));
}

@Override
public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView < ? > parent) {

}
```

Comment: so you changed something. what did you Change exactely?

Comment: what is the value of Kilometer you are getting? Try to put a log and see. Also what is km? are you getting any exception?

Comment: I removed one line from this code I don't know what the line exsist   Circle circle = mMap.addCircle(new CircleOptions()
                    .center(new LatLng(latitude, longitude))
                    .radius(kilometer)
                    .strokeColor(Color.RED)
                    .fillColor(Color.BLUE));

Comment: km is spinner id